# Why does my blog not show up on the planet feed?

Tags: wordpress, feeds, rss-reader

My blog (ankursinha.in/blog) is configured to show up on planet Fedora: http://planet.fedoraproject.org but posts aren't appearing on the planet. I'm using a self hosted wordpress site. The admins looked into it and said that the planet gets a 406 error while trying to access feeds from my blog:

```
ERROR:planet.runner:Error 406 while updating feed
http://ankursinha.in/blog/category/fedora/feed/
```

I've checked the feed and it works just fine here in Firefox. I also tested it in Liferea and it works there too. This is what "ismyblogworking" says: http://ismyblogworking.com/ankursinha.in/blog

I've looked around quite a bit but I can't find any thing about this. Would any one know how to debug/fix this error please?

Answer (score 1):

The 406 seems to stem from a user agent error that my server doesn't seem to like.

```
# venus uses httplib2 underneath
import httplib2
h = httplib2.Http()
resp, content = h.request("http://ankursinha.in/blog/feed/", headers={'user-agent': 'trolololololol'})
```

works just fine. I'm still uncertain if the issue is in httplib2 or some server configuration, but changing the agent seems to work around it for the time being.